# HTML5 Canvas with Javascript , Image loading

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Web Game </title>
</head>
<body onkeydown="keyDown(event)" onkeyup="keyUp(event)"></body>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas1" width=600 height=400 style ="position:absoloute:top:0;left:0;background-image:url('img/background.jpg')">
        Please upgrade your browser to support HTML5.<br/> 
        One recommendation is to install the latest Chrome or Firefox.
    </canvas>


  <script>
   gamecanvas = document.getElementById("gamecanvas1");
   ctx=gamecanvas.getContext("2d");

  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "img/left.png";


  //MainLoop
  MainLoop();
  function MainLoop(){
    grafx.drawImage(img,0,0)};

  setTimeout(MainLoop, 1000/60); //about 60fps
  }
  </script>


</html>
```

I am trying to load the left.png image. I am making a basic platformer in HTML and JavaScript, but the image isn't being shown. I think the drawImage is being called before the image is loaded but I'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems I found.

**P1:**

`grafx.drawImage(img,0,0)};` is wrong

it should be

`ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);`

**P2:**
use image onload callback rather than setTimeout.

```
img.onload = function () {
   ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your js code.

your element has an `id` of `gameCanvas1`, but you are trying to get an element with an id of `gamecanvas1` (`document.getElementById("gamecanvas1");`)

So the javascript wont find your canvas, which means the image wont be drawn. You also have an extra closing `}` which is causing errors in your function

Try opening your browsers dev console, you'll see the issues

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Web Game </title>
    </head>
    <body onkeydown="keyDown(event)" onkeyup="keyUp(event)"></body>

        <canvas id="gameCanvas1" width=600 height=400 style ="position:absoloute:top:0;left:0;background-image:url('img/background.jpg')">
            Please upgrade your browser to support HTML5.<br/> 
            One recommendation is to install the latest Chrome or Firefox.
        </canvas>


      <script>
       console.log("i am here ");
       var gamecanvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas1');
       var ctx=gamecanvas.getContext('2d');

       var img = new Image();
       img.src = "img/left.png";


       //MainLoop
       MainLoop();
        function MainLoop(){

        ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
        setTimeout(function(){
          MainLoop();
          }, 1000/60); //about 60fps
      }
      </script>


    </html>
```